# A few questions about the morphology and sediment dynamics of Wissant Bay (France)

Tags: geography, sedimentology, coastal

Could someone please explain what exactly is shown on the following image? I have a few questions such as:

[image: Image of a map]

How did the 'Banc à la Ligne' come about? (I know it has something to do with the fact that the beach drift is subject to south-west winds, and the orientation change of the coast)

Why are the western sectors (Dune du Chatelet, Dune d'Aval) eroded in contrast to the more eastern locations (Dune d'Amont)?

I read somewhere that the height of the dunes is increasing towards the east, what is the explanation for this?